# DoubleUpDown increment by one with Page Up and Down

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xceed

I would like to extend a DoubleUpDown from the Xceed - Toolkits, so that it works with PageUp and PageDown keys.
The usual increment behaviour should be incrementing by 0.1, but if I use the PgUP or PgDn Keys the number should be incremented by 1.

Any ideas?

Thanks
Steve

Comment: Have you tried using `InputBindings` and binding the PgUp and PgDn to a command where you can increment the value?

Comment: @MightyBadaboom what do you mean exactly. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Have a look at my answer

Comment: @MightyBadaboom there is no property called InputBindings "https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/DoubleUpDown"

Comment: I downloaded the xceed package and I did not get any compile errors with the code in my answer. I can't start it but only because I don't have a licence. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an `KeyBinding` for this.

Assuming value of the `DoubleUpDown` is stored in the `Value` property because I don't have the xceed toolkit.

```
<xctk:DoubleUpDown Value="{Binding MyValue}">
    <xctk:DoubleUpDown.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="PageUp"
                    Command="{Binding IncrementCommand}"/>
    </xctk:DoubleUpDown.InputBindings>
</xctk:DoubleUpDown>
```

In your viewmodel you bind the value to `MyValue` and in the `IncrementCommand` you increment this value.

Comment: Hi @MightyBadaboom the problem with this solution is that the up or down spinner have to be focused, otherwise it wouldn't work.